# How to find duplicates rows in the results of a multiple table query

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

In Oracle:

There are lots of examples available on how to find duplicates in a single table but none, that I could find, which do so for a query.

How should I enhance the following query to return duplicate rows with all three columns

```
SELECT a.c1, b.c1, c.c1
FROM tableA a JOIN tableB b on a.ID = b.ID
JOIN tableC as c on a.ID = c.ID AND b.ID = c.ID
```

I've tried GROUP BY and HAVING clauses but to no avail.

I'd appreciate your help along with any examples

Thank you!

Comment: You should show what you tried.

Comment: You have an errant `as` between `tableC` and the alias `c` in your last line of code - be advised that it will cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you tried?

```
SELECT a.c1, b.c1, c.c1
FROM tableA a JOIN
     tableB b 
     ON a.ID = b.ID JOIN
     tableC c 
     ON a.ID = c.ID AND b.ID = c.ID
GROUP BY a.c1, b.c1, c.c1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: I did, but it worked this time. I must have had some other error.

Thank you!